# Node - get all instances of an Angular filter

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm working on localizing an Angular app that is currently in development.  There currently exists a filter for localizing text has been implemented as such:

```
<button>{{ 'This is my localized text.' | i18n }}</button>
<button>{{ 'This is more text.' | i18n }}</button>
<button>{{ 'Look at all this text.' | i18n }}</button>
```

What I want to do is parse my app for all instances of the `i18n` filter and output it's key (or the phrase to localize) into JSON file formatted as such:

```
{
    "This is my localized text." : "This is my localized text.",
    "This is more text." : "This is more text.",
    "Look at all this text." : "Look at all this text."
}
```

In this instance, value of the entry could be blank, but the key need to the the placeholder phrase so the filter knows what to look for.

I've done a days worth of googling and haven't come up with a solution yet.

We're using Grunt, so if some existing plugin can achieve this, that would be awesome.

**EDIT 1:** I've gotten a little closer with `grunt-search`.  I'm having issues with the regex for find the string as account for any wildcards.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    search: {   
        i18n: {
            files: {
                src: ["**/*.html"]
            },
            options: {
                searchString: /\{\{ * \| i18n \}\}/,
                logFile: "results.json"
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: I would have wrote a python script that can parse all the files looking out for pattern {{*+\|i18n}} . Did you try anything in those lines ?